# O Class.getResource() só consegue recuperar arquivos em pastas internas às que a classe se encontra?

Tags: java, arquivo

Nessa classe, eu preciso ler arquivos `*.properties` que estão em uma outra pasta/pacote do projeto. A estrutura de pastas é essa:

> util → properties (aqui ficam os .properties)
>
> util → server → consultas (aqui fica a classe que vai ler os .properties)

```
package util.server.consultas;
import java.io.File;
import org.restlet.Response;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;
public class ConsultasResource extends ServerResource {

  @Get
  public Response returnConsulta() throws Exception {
    File dir = new File(getClass().getResource(/*Como proceder aqui?*/"").toExternalForm());
    return getResponse();
  }
}
```

E existe a possibilidade desse método poder funcionar caso eu extraia o arquivo para .jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver aqui, segue o código:

```
package util.server.consultas;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

import org.restlet.Response;
import org.restlet.data.MediaType;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

public class ConsultasResource extends ServerResource {

  @Get
  public Response returnConsultas() throws Exception {
    Response response = getResponse();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    File dir = new File("C:/Users/<usuario>/workspace/projeto/src/util/properties/consultas");
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    File arq = null;
    for(int i = 0; i<files.length; i++) {
        arq = files[i];
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(arq);
        while(reader.ready()) {
            sb.append(Character.toChars(reader.read()));
        }
        reader.close();
    };
    response.setEntity(sb.toString(), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    return response;
  }
}
```

Isso pega o texto de todos os arquivos .properties da pasta Consultas.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você faz:

```
getClass().getResource()
```

ele irá considerar o pacote da classe (caminho relativo a partir da classe).

Quando você faz:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()
```

ele irá considerar a raiz do ClassLoader (caminho absoluto a partir do classLoader).

Portanto, esses aqui são equivalentes para você:

```
util.server.consultas.SuaClasse.class.getResource("/util/properties/bla.properties");
util.server.consultas.SuaClasse.class.getClassLoader().getResource("util/properties/bla.properties");
```

[retirado do SO inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource/6608848#6608848)

**Está utilizando JAX-RS ?**

Notei pelos imports. Se você quiser devolver um recurso de dentro do seu WAR (a partir da pasta webapp), injete o ServletContext no seu endPoint colocando um propriedade no seu servlet:

```
@javax.ws.rs.core.Context 
private ServletContext context;
```

e faça:

```
servletContext.getResource("/...");
```

Comment: Eu estou usando a biblioteca Restlet. É de certa forma similar.